# Composer runtime error 'rm' when installing Cachet

Tags: apache, composer-php, runtimeexception, rm

I am trying to install Composer on a Windows apache server to run Cachet - https://cachethq.io/

I have run composer on the same Apache server fine in the past but when I try to install composer in my Cachet folder I am getting a runtime error....

```
[Runtime Exception]
Error Output: 'rm' is not a recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Screenshot attached for reference. Any ideas on why I am getting this error would be very helpful. I have all the requirements installed for Cachet but Composer just won't install in my folder for Cachet.

Screenshot of error here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/geqZD.jpg

Comment: Hi there! I'm the creator of Cachet, I didn't think anybody would post to Stackoverflow. If you're still getting issues with your Cachet installation or gave up and would like to try again, please email us at support@alt-three.com :)

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Cachet no longer include these commands, which means that Cachet will work on Windows.

Also, you can follow our Windows installation documentation at https://docs.cachethq.io/docs/installing-cachet-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

That command comes from `pre-install-cmd` inside [Cachet's composer.json](https://github.com/cachethq/Cachet/blob/1.1/composer.json#L62-L64) and because it is a Unix command, does not work in Windows:

```
"pre-install-cmd": [
    "rm -f compiled.php config.php routes.php services.json"
],
```

You can use `composer install --no-scripts` in order to skip execution of those commands and install Cachet under Windows.

Comment: Thanks. I installed Composer correctly, installed the database tables but now all I get is a 500 error when trying to run the setup page.